# Default request method of HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, http, https

What is the default request method of `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`?
That is whether **`GET`** or **`POST`** is default, if I do not specify any method type explicitly?

What method type is used in following codes - **`GET?`** or **`POST?`**

```
protected URLConnection createUrlConnection(URL url) throws IOException,
            GeneralSecurityException, LinkKeyStoreException
    {
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
        {
            ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection).setHostnameVerifier(Constants.ACCEPT_ALL_HOSTS);
            ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(createSSLSocketFactory());
        }
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(Constants.URL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(Constants.URL_READ_TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + totalBytesDownloaded + "-");
        urlConnection.connect();
        return urlConnection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method is `GET`, and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-) for `HttpUrlConnection#setRequestMethod` hints at this:

> Set the method for the URL request, one of:
>   GET
>   POST
>   HEAD
>   OPTIONS
>   PUT
>   DELETE
>   TRACE
>   are legal, subject to protocol restrictions. **The default method is GET.**

Comment: Not applicable to this Q, and the javadoc doesn't say, but if you supply request body with `.setDoOutput(true)` and `.getOutputStream()` without explicitly changing method it uses POST since HTTP prohibits body on GET.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah...I also saw that `if` statement in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default.